# Suppose $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is a Markov Chain, would it be the case that $(Y_n)_{n\geq 0}:=X_{n+1}-X_n$ also a Markov Chain?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Suppose $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is a Markov Chain, would it be the case that $(Y_n)_{n\geq 0}:=X_{n+1}-X_n$ is also a Markov Chain? To avoid any potential confusion, what I meant was $Y_0=X_1-X_0$, $Y_1=X_2-X_1,\cdots .$

I am really not sure how to prove this or disprove this. My intuition tells me that since $X_{n+1}$ only depends on $X_n$ (loosely speaking) and thus $X_{n+1}-X_n$ should also just only depends on $X_n-X_{n-1}$ (loosely speaking). However I could not convert this intuition to a proper, rigorous argument.

Could someone please help me with this rather simple-looking problem? Many many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: think about the gambler's ruin problem where the gambler stops at certain money thresholds. Does knowing whether the gambler won his last game tell you whether he plays the next one?

Comment: @Ian Ah Understood! Thank you so much Ian!

Comment: Since that helped you, I'll just copy it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: think about the gambler's ruin problem where the gambler stops at certain money thresholds. Does knowing whether the gambler won his last game tell you whether he plays the next one?